# SubString in query CQL

Tags: string, cassandra, cql

It is possible to found a substring in a String in CQL ?
For exemple, make a query like this :

`select id from table where string contains 'do'`
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible with the usage of Storage Attached Index (SASI). Your query will be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE colname LIKE 'do%';
```

Have a look at [official documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useSASIIndex.html) on how to use it.

Comment: Humm That's what I want but it doesn't work. I create this `create table test (id int, string text, primary key (id));`. Then i created an index on string and after i did this query : `select * from test where string like 'and';` and I have no answer. I already try with a % in the like clause but the problem is already here.

Comment: @AlexandreS. Show us your index definition and your query.

Comment: There is my index : `create custom index test on test(string) USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex' WITH OPTIONS = { 'mode': 'CONTAINS', 'analyzer_class': 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.analyzer.StandardAnalyzer', 'analyzed': 'true', 'tokenization_skip_stop_words': 'and, the, or', 'tokenization_enable_stemming': 'true', 'tokenization_normalize_lowercase': 'true', 'tokenization_locale': 'en' };`. And my query : `select * from test where string like 'and'`

Comment: I'm using Cassandra 3.6

Comment: @AlexandreS. `Select * from test where string like '%and%'`

Comment: Still 0 rows returned, did I miss something ? My table containes this 2 lines : `insert into test (id, string) values (1, 'test');`
`insert into test (id, string) values (2, 'banana and black');`

Comment: @AlexandreS. I see you're using the `StandardAnalyzer` skipping `and`. With this in mind please verify you are able to fetch by other words (eg insert a record with a sentence with the word `cassandra` and look for `%sand%`).

Comment: Well, i'm tryin to insert another row into my table, as you said. But I had another error : `WriteTimeout: Error from server: code=1100 [Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes' responses] message="Operation timed out - received only 0 responses." info={'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'ONE'} `